# Getting undefined when calling collection.fineOne in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

This is my router.js file in the `root` of my app. For some reason I keep getting an undefined for `question`.

```
Router.map( function() {
    this.route('question_display', {
        path: '/questions/:_id/:title?',
        template: 'display_question',
        yieldTemplates: {
            'header': {to: 'header'},
            'footer': {to: 'footer'}
        },
        waitOn : function () { 
            return Meteor.subscribe('questions');
        },
        before: function () {
            var id = this.params._id;
            var question = Questions.findOne({_id: id});
            console.log(question);
            Router.go('postShow', {_id: id, title: question.title});
        }
    });
});
```

I've also got some code in my `publish.js` file that is located in the `/server/` directory

```
Meteor.publish('questions', function () { 
    return Questions.find({}); 
});
```

I'm not sure what's actually wrong. I've done this before but there was no issue, however, now I keep getting an undefined when I try to look for the document. This document does exist in my database by the way.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to wrap your `Questions.findOne` with `if (this.ready() == true)`. Essentially it needs to wait for the subscription to be ready.